# AttributeOverride and CollectionOfElements, column annotattion is ignored

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Code from my Entity **Role**

```
   @Embedded 
   @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
   @CollectionOfElements
   @JoinTable(name = "TEST_TABLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
   @AttributeOverrides({
      @AttributeOverride(name = "code", column = @Column(name = "TSTCODE")),
      @AttributeOverride(name = "work", column = @Column(name = "TSTWRK"))
   })
       private List<TestID> tests;  
}
```

TestID class

```
@Embeddable
@AccessType("field")
public class TestID implements Serializable 
{
   private String code;

   private String work;  

// getters, setters  
}
```

Get exception **SQLGrammarException**

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00904: "TESTS0_"."WORK": invalid identifier
```

Entity manager create query that trying get access to columns CODE and WORK instead of TSTCODE and TSTWRk that are in *@Column* annotations.
Any ideas?

*Hibernate-annotation 3.2.1.ga

persistance-api 1.0

jboss-4.2.3.GA*

**UPDATE:**

if rename fields in TestID class to table's columns names, then all warks normally

```
@Embeddable
@AccessType("field")
public class TestID implements Serializable 
{
   private String tstcode;

   private String tstwks;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `@CollectionOfElements` and just use `@Embedded`. I think you're double-mapping it as it is right now. Also, JPA's `@ElementCollection` is [recommended over](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html/collections.html#d0e11155) Hibernate's `@CollectionOfElements`.

**Update**: I kinda missed the fact that you're mapping a collection of components. You'll want to add an `@Column(name="...")` to the fields in your `TestID` to make it map correctly in that case. Even though it's somewhat contrary to the way embedded components are supposed to work, that's the only way I know to do it.

Comment: Remove @CollectionOfElements -> List<TestId> always empty. Records were not found

Comment: @user1143825: Updated my answer. I had missed an important detail.

Comment: Temporary, I solved this problem in the same way. But in this case, I cann't use TestId in another Entities

Comment: That seems to suggest that TestID isn't a component, but an entity itself. Components, by their very nature, are an integral part of exactly one entity. They aren't shared between other entities. That's what entity relationships are for.

Answer (score 1):

According to the hibernate [recommendations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#entity-mapping-association) (`2.2.5.3.3. Collection of basic types or embeddable objects`) you should use

```
@ElementCollection
@CollectionTable(name="TEST_TABLE", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "ROLE_ID"))
@AttributeOverrides({
     @AttributeOverride(name = "code", column = @Column(name = "TSTCODE")),
     @AttributeOverride(name = "work", column = @Column(name = "TSTWRK"))
})
```

Comment: @ElementCollection since JPA 2.0. JBoss 4.2.3 doesn't support JPA 2.0, only JPA 1.0